# Unable to install python package (gspread.v4)

Tags: python, python-3.x, package, gspread

I am trying to export my Dataframe to Google sheets and came across a package called gspread. While installing this package it asks for a module named gspread.v4 but when i try to do a pip install get

```
Collecting gspread.v4

 Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement gspread.v4 (from versions: )

No matching distribution found for gspread.v4
```

Could anyone help me on this.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you expand your example and show what command are you using to install gspread? (e.g. pip install gspread)

Comment: @Burnash, given below is what I tried:

pip install gspread.v4

Collecting gspread.v4
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement gspread.v4 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for gspread.v4

Comment: the correct command is `pip install gspread`. How did you come across the incorrect command you're using? Was it in the docs somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

To install gspread you need to specify `gspread` as a package name when using `pip`:

```
pip install gspread
```

Please refer to the [gspread](https://github.com/burnash/gspread) repo for more information and examples.

Comment: I have gspread installed. When I try to import the package, I get an error asking to install gspread.v4

Comment: Please try installing with `pip install -U gspread`. `-U` stands for "upgrade".